# Using Confidence Intervals to Construct Effect Size Bounds

Tags: statistical-significance, confidence-interval, effect-size

Suppose I have two binomial random variables $X_1$ and $X_2$ and I want to estimate the probability of successes $p_1$ and $p_2$ so that I can determine if $p_1 > p_2$ along with the effect size, which in this context is $p_2$ - $p_1$.

I collect some samples and construct confidence intervals ($l_1$, $u_1$) and ($l_2$, $u_2$) around $p_1$ and $p_2$, respectively. Let's suppose that the confidence intervals do not overlap. Can I then use these intervals to compute bounds on the effect size? 
For example, if $l_2$ > $u_1$ can I infer that the effect is at least $l_2$ - $u_1$? Are there any problems with this approach? Is there a better one?

Comment: $p_2 - p_1$ is an effect size. Do you have a particular effect size type you want to estimate? Are you hoping to create a CI around your effect size or just a central estimate?

Comment: Are you simply asking if the confidence intervals of $p_1$ and $p_2$ overlap, then is $p_1-p_2$ statistically significant?

Comment: Thanks for the clarifying questions. I've edited my original question for clarity. I'm looking for how to construct bounds on the effect size (in this context the effect size is $p_2$ - $p_1$)  It seems like a lower bound on the effect size must be at least $l_2$ - $u_1$ if $l_2$ > $u_1$, but I've only seen this used as a hack without any theoretical justification, and I'm wondering if there's any reason not to use that as a bound.